# How can I write a list of matrices to a text file and read that text file back to a list?

Tags: r, file-writing, file-read

I have a list of matrices, a simple enough object to work with within an R session, but I want to write this list to a file in a readable format, AND be able to recover the list back from the file when desired or called.

As a simple example of what my list looks like structurally:

```
My_list

$foo
     'Col_1' 'Col_2' 'Col_3'
[1,] 'a'     'b'     '1'
[2,] 'c'     'd'     '2'

$bar
     'Col_1' 'Col_2' 'Col_3'
[1,] 'w'     'x'     '3'
[2,] 'y'     'z'     '4'
```

I can *write* it to a file quite easily:

```
capture.output(My_list, file = 'My_file.txt')
```

But I would also like to *read* My_file.txt back and exactly recover My_list. How can I do this? The general gist of what I'm after is:

```
Reading_variable <- Reading_function('My_file.txt')



Reading_variable

$foo
     'Col_1' 'Col_2' 'Col_3'
[1,] 'a'     'b'     '1'
[2,] 'c'     'd'     '2'

$bar
     'Col_1' 'Col_2' 'Col_3'
[1,] 'w'     'x'     '3'
[2,] 'y'     'z'     '4'
```

Whereby Reading_variable == My_list

Comment: There's no built in functions that are designed to turn arbitrary printed output from text back into an R object. If you want to save data to load it letter, it would be much safer to use something like `saveRDS` and `readRDS` (though they use binary formats rather than text formats).

Comment: if `saveRDS`, `readRDS` isn't an option, (may be because you want to share intermediate results). Converting list elements to `data.frame` and then writing to csv and reading them back could be an option

Comment: SaveRDS may be a possibility, there is already a place in this project where I save a human-readable and R-readable form of the same data as separate filetypes, just in the previous case it was a package-custom object with package-custom read/write functions and a package-custom filetype, so I was not aware of saveRDS/readRDS. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

the comments about saveRDS & readRDS did the trick, now my code saves an .RDS file and .TXT file of the same list in parallel, the latter can be loaded back into R later, the former can be inspected by eye as I intended.